# Android - Support.v7 Preferences unable to open fragments

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I want to implement `android.support.v7.preference` to my app. I have created a settings activity on android which worked fine and Now i want to use this support library.

Default `AppCompatPreferenceActivity` made by Android Studio:

```
public abstract class AppCompatPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

private AppCompatDelegate mDelegate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDelegate().installViewFactory();
    getDelegate().onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getDelegate().onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
    return getDelegate().getSupportActionBar();
}

public void setSupportActionBar(@Nullable Toolbar toolbar) {
    getDelegate().setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
    return getDelegate().getMenuInflater();
}

@Override
public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
    getDelegate().setContentView(layoutResID);
}

@Override
public void setContentView(View view) {
    getDelegate().setContentView(view);
}

@Override
public void setContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    getDelegate().setContentView(view, params);
}

@Override
public void addContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    getDelegate().addContentView(view, params);
}

@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    getDelegate().onPostResume();
}

@Override
protected void onTitleChanged(CharSequence title, int color) {
    super.onTitleChanged(title, color);
    getDelegate().setTitle(title);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    getDelegate().onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    getDelegate().onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    getDelegate().onDestroy();
}

public void invalidateOptionsMenu() {
    getDelegate().invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

private AppCompatDelegate getDelegate() {
    if (mDelegate == null) {
        mDelegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, null);
    }
    return mDelegate;
}
```

My `SettingsActivity`:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        NecessaryActivityUtils.checksVerifiedOrReload(this);
        setupActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
        return isXLargeTablet(this);
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to determine if the device has an extra-large screen. For
     * example, 10" tablets are extra-large.
     */
    private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    }

    /**
     * A preference value change listener that updates the preference's summary
     * to reflect its new value.
     */
    private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
            String stringValue = value.toString();

            if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
                // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
                // the preference's 'entries' list.
                ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
                int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

                // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
                preference.setSummary(
                        index >= 0
                                ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                                : null);

            }
//            else if (preference instanceof RingtonePreference) {
//                // For ringtone preferences, look up the correct display value
//                // using RingtoneManager.
//                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue)) {
//                    // Empty values correspond to 'silent' (no ringtone).
//
//                } else {
//                    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
//                            preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue));
//
//                    if (ringtone == null) {
//                        // Clear the summary if there was a lookup error.
//                        preference.setSummary(null);
//                    } else {
//                        // Set the summary to reflect the new ringtone display
//                        // name.
//                        String name = ringtone.getTitle(preference.getContext());
//                        preference.setSummary(name);
//                    }
//                }
//
//            }
            else {
                // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
                // simple string representation.
                preference.setSummary(stringValue);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    /**
     * Binds a preference's summary to its value. More specifically, when the
     * preference's value is changed, its summary (line of text below the
     * preference title) is updated to reflect the value. The summary is also
     * immediately updated upon calling this method. The exact display format is
     * dependent on the type of preference.
     *
     * @see #sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener
     */
    private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
        // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

        // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
        // current value.
        sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
                PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                        .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }

    /**
     * This method stops fragment injection in malicious applications.
     * Make sure to deny any unknown fragments here.
     */
    protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
        return PreferenceFragmentCompat.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || AdvancedPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || HelpPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
//                || NotificationPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows general preferences only. It is used when the
     * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class AdvancedPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String s) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_advanced);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("language_chooser"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("min_num_of_percents"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("min_num_of_words"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class HelpPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String ex) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_help);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            Preference about = findPreference("pref_about");
            about.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), AboutActivity.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(i);
                    return true;
                }
            });
            Preference visit_our_site = findPreference("pref_visit_our_site");
            visit_our_site.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse("https://**.com/"));
                    getActivity().startActivity(i);
                    return true;
                }
            });
            Preference contact = findPreference("pref_contact_us");
            contact.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ContactUsActivity.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(i);
                    return true;
                }
            });
            Preference openSource = findPreference("pref_open_source_license");
            openSource.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), OpenSourceLicensesActivity.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(i);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
            // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
            // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
            // guidelines.
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

When entering one of the headers the app crashes here:

```
at **.settings.AppCompatPreferenceActivity.onCreate(AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java:27)
at **.settings.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:25)
```

And the reason is:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{**/**.settings.SettingsActivity}: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class **.settings.SettingsActivity$AdvancedPreferenceFragment that is not a Fragment
```

As it seems the problem is that i am using `PreferenceFragmentCompat` instead of `PreferenceFragmentCompat` but i have to in order to use the support library features.

What can i do here?

Comment: Did you find a solution?